# find rows where the variable “back” is greater than 100

Tags: r, excel

The question is write the code to provide the rows where the variable “back” is greater than 100.I am a new for the R,now I only use `x<-read.csv('data.csv',header = TRUE)` to load the excel, just want to know how to find rows which value more than 100

Comment: Just do `which(x$back > 100)`

Comment: Or if you want to see the whole row, `subset(x, back > 100)`.

Comment: Alternatively, use `library(dplyr)` and then `x %>% filter(back > 100)`.  This can accommodate multiple filtration criteria at once.

Comment: @akrun thanks for you answer, its works, but the row number it is after the correct row number, which mean is the more than 100 value row in 74 in excel, but its show 73 in R, I think it is not include the first  column names, do you have any way to fix this problem?

Comment: row number doesn't include the column name. If you want to add that use `c(1, which(x$back > 100) + 1)`

Comment: @GregorThomas thanks for you answer, its works, but it is also show other row whic is some row is not more than 100, should I add something to only show the one column?

Comment: See the `?subset` help page, if you only want to see the `back` column, `subset(x, back > 100, select = back)`

Comment: @akrun thank you so much, I use c(which(x$back > 100) + 1) it is works for me, because when I add 1, it is always show the 1 row in the first,but the first row do not have valuse more than 100

Comment: @Eren I meant the `1` as the column names as you mentioned that it is what you are missing

Comment: @akrun I got it, thanks a lot

Comment: @GregorThomas it is look like very good, can I plus one for showing the row numbers? because  some more than 100 value row in 50 in excel, but its show 49 in R, I think it is not include the first column names?

Comment: of course @akrun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a logical vector with the comparison operator (`>`), get the positions by wrapping with `which` and if we need to include the column names as index 1, then concatenate 1 and add 1 to the index we got with `which`

```
c(1, which(x$back > 100) + 1)
```